# AngularJS after drag drop controller not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with implementing drag and drop functionality with swapping of elements.
I used jquery-ui to implement drag-drop functionality and there are ng-controllers inside each draggable elements.

Once drag-drop happens dragged element and dropped element swaps their position. But after this happen ng-controller click event not working for those controller. Drag drop functionality implemented as below

```
drgObj = {
    revert : 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone'
}

drpObj = {
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function(event, ui){
        var drag_item = ui.draggable;
        var drop_item = $(this);
        var drag_clone = drag_item.clone();
        var drop_clone = drop_item.clone();

        drop_item.after(drag_clone);
        $(drag_item).after(drop_clone);

        $(drag_item).remove();
        drop_item.remove();

        $('.drag-drop').draggable(drgObj);
        $('.drag-drop').droppable(drpObj);
    }
};

$('.drag-drop').draggable(drgObj)
$('.drag-drop').droppable(drpObj)
```

This situation demonstrated in this 
http://jsfiddle.net/0jennzbw/

I tried some angular directives for drag-drop
    https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable,
    https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop,
    https://github.com/petrkotek/angular-widgetarea-directive
but it didn't work for me

Anybody give any help to solve these issue?